# Introducing myself to a research mentor

Tags: phd, conference, networking, mentoring

I am a PhD student and apart from academic supervisors I also have a mentor. This mentor I haven't met in person yet and have only communicated through email once. But I am going to meet the mentor in person in a conference. My question is how am I going to introduce myself to him? It is important for me to make a good connection with this mentor. Since I wrote that email  long time ago he might not remember me at all.

How do I approach him? Should I mention to him that he is my mentor and then explain to him what I am doing in my research?
Is it okay to say that he is being assigned as my mentor ? How can I say this politely?

Comment: Who assigned him to be your mentor? How was he informed about it? (By your mail?) Did he agree? This situation seems very strange to me to be honest...

Comment: Agree with @JayFromA ... very strange. Voting to close as unclear because in no universe I am familiar with are folks assigned as mentors without them even knowing about it.

Comment: A mentor that you don't know and have no contact with? That seems not overly useful.

Comment: You probably don't mean mentor. Maybe your role model? Or personal hero? Once you get to talk with him he might become your mentor if you two click at intellectual level.

Comment: @MadJack Just because you're not familiar with it doesn't mean it doesn't happen. The guy probably signed up to some kind of voluntary mentoring programme, and it was probably left up to the new PhDs to introduce themselves to their mentors. Not implausible at all given the notoriously disorganised and half-assed nature of most academic administration. It's probably part of some box-ticking exercise anyway and OP doesn't realise it's not actually meant to be useful.

Comment: _Just because you're not familiar with it doesn't mean it doesn't happen._ -- This is one of the key things I've learned here on this SE, so, of course, I agree. Still doesn't mean that the question is not unclear. @user234461

Comment: "Hi, I'm Sam. I believe you're my assigned mentor."

Comment: @MadJack You literally used the words "*because* in no universe I am familiar with are folks assigned as mentors without them even knowing about it". If you now admit that your basis for believing it doesn't happen is flawed, and you justify your argument that the question is unclear by your assertion that it doesn't happen, then your argument is now wrong and you have no basis for calling for the question to be closed without clarifying your position and justifying why you think the question is unclear, which you have so far failed to do.

Comment: @user234461 The question is unclear. OP needs to elaborate more. It is really that simple.

Comment: @madjack: This situation is vommon in my University. Mentors get assigned which then have no interest in meeting the students which are to be mentored.

Answer (score 1):

Schedule a time to talk in advance.  Email him again, mention how he came to be identified as your mentor (as a reminder, in case he forgot), and ask if you could get lunch with him or meet whenever is convenient during the conference.  In my experience, many researchers have packed schedules during conferences and may not have the time to speak with you when you find him.